# UWP Page Navigation with "Frame.Navigate();"

Tags: navigation, uwp

I'm a bit confused about switching pages in a UWP application.

I have two pages, "MainPage" and "Rooms".
There is a button in "MainPage" and if it is clicked,
the "Rooms" page should be displayed.

Code of "MainPage":

```cs
namespace UWPTest1
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Rooms));
    }
}
```

Code of "Rooms":

```cs
namespace UWPTest1
{
    public sealed partial class Rooms : Page
    {
        public Rooms()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I've already tried to navigate in many different ways (also solutions from stackoverflow), but nothing worked for me, so I redused the code to what it looked like when I started and hope someone can help me.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: This looks fine to me, what is it thats not working? Are you certain the click event is linked to your button?

Comment: Please show the XAML markup for your button controls. Did you assign a `Click` handler?

Comment: That was the problem, thank you so much! there was actually no click event in the XAML code. I thought that was added automatically when i double-clicked the event in the designer.